# Keep only data in pandas dataframe where column value occurs more than once for a groupby arrangement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID 1          ID 2
1             5
1             5
1             6
2             7
2             5
2             7
3             8
3             9
3             10
```

What I am trying to do is only keep the rows that, when the df is grouped by ID 1, ID 2 exists more than once. I have used .groupby and .value_counts in this method:

```
df_temp = df.groupby('ID 1')
df_output = df_temp['ID 2'].value_counts()[df_temp1['ID 2'].value_counts() > 1]
```

This returns something like so:

```
ID 1          ID 2
1             5         2
2             7         2
```

Is there a way I can use this in order to only keep the rows in the initial df with the ID 2 in this groupedby object? To get a result like this:

```
ID 1          ID 2
1             5
1             5
2             7
2             7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `groupby`, perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
out = df[df.duplicated(['id1', 'id2'], keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
   id1  id2
0    1    5
1    1    5
3    2    7
5    2    7
```

Comment: I like this solution better. This returns my work to the original df level and does not require me to get the counts, filter by counts, then return to the original df level.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [422]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id1=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], id2=[5,5,6,7,5,7,8,9,10]))

In [423]: df
Out[423]:
   id1  id2
0    1    5
1    1    5
2    1    6
3    2    7
4    2    5
5    2    7
6    3    8
7    3    9
8    3   10

In [424]: counts = pd.DataFrame(df.value_counts(subset=['id1', 'id2']))

In [425]: counts
Out[425]:
         0
id1 id2
2   7    2
1   5    2
3   10   1
    9    1
    8    1
2   5    1
1   6    1

In [426]: counts[counts[0]>1]
Out[426]:
         0
id1 id2
2   7    2
1   5    2
```

Comment: This works great, but how can I then get the value and merge this to the original df? The outputted df only has the one column ```0```, so I am not sure how to handle this

Comment: df['myCol'] = counts[0]. Or use [df.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)